# Using regroup in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm receiving a JSON object that contains many objects and lists of objects etc. In one of those lists is Year list like this:

```
[{'Year': '2015', 'Status': 'NR', 'Month': 'Jan'
{'Year': '2014', Status': '', 'Month': 'Jan'}, 
{'Year': '2015', 'Status': '',Month': 'Feb'}, 
{'Year': '2014', Status': '', 'Month': 'Feb'}, 
{'Year': '2015', 'Status': '', Month': 'Sep'}, 
{'Year': '2014', 'Status': 'OK', 'Month': 'Sep'}, 
{'Year': '2015', 'Status': '', 'Month': 'Oct'}, 
{'Year': '2014', 'Status': 'OK', 'Month': 'Oct'}]
```

I need to group this list by Year and display months according to their year. For example:

```
{"2015":[{"Month":"Jan", "Status":"NR"}, {"Month" : "Feb". "Status" :""}]
```

Right now, the code I'm using doesn't work the way I want it to, instead it repeats the years according to the number of months:

```
2015                                                
2014                                                
2015                                                
2014                                                
2015                                                
2014                                                
2015                                                
2014
```

This is the code:

```
{% regroup x.LstPaymentBehaviour by Year as yearList %} 
  {% for ym in yearList  %}
    <tr>
           <td><strong>{{ ym.grouper }}</strong></td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting any error? If yes, then what exactly is it?

Comment: Okay so what exactly do you see? Is the loop running? If yes, then how many number of times?

Comment: Where is the JSON object coming from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

docs: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

`regroup` expects ordered data in the first place. If all the items with same year are consecutive then you will get the desired output. So first sort your input data

```
{% regroup x.LstPaymentBehaviour|dictsort:'Year' by Year as yearList %}
```